# How to redirect based on api versioning in header in haproxy?

Tags: api, haproxy

```
frontend http
  bind *:8000
  acl v1 hdr(ContentType) ??
  acl users_create path_reg ^/users/create/?

  use_backend users_create if users_create v1
```

The requests are going to have "Content-Type: application/vnd.hello.v1+json". Not sure how I can match just the v1 part.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hdr_sub will match if the header contains the specified substring.
`acl v1 hdr_sub(Content-Type)  v1`

You can alternatively use hdr_reg to match on a regular expression.

Other hdr options exist for matching just the beging or end of a string in a header, and other attributes.  See docs for details: https://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/MatchingLayer7